# parsing data out of formatted plain-text

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am trying to periodically pull billing out of a .PDF report. The report is plain text, and a single record example is listed below. manually pulling the billing data isn't difficult, it's just time consuming because the report can be 1000's of records. I need to be able to pass this task off to a non-technical person, so ideally the data could be parsed out using Excel 2016, or Word 2016 after we copy/paste the text out of the .PDF.

Here is a sample record. For each unique Claim # we need to pull the first Claim Total, hopefully ending with a 2-column listing:

[Claim #]   [Claim Total]

```
====================================================================================================================================
Ins. Co. Name: XXXX [XXXXXXXXX] EFT #: XXXXXX EFT Date: XX/XX/XXXX
Claim #: 9999999
Patient Name: XXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX X Date of Birth: X/XX/XXXX Patient Acct#: XXXXXXXXXX
Member ID: XXXXXXXXX Group: XXXXX-XX [XXXXXXXXX]
SERVICE PROCEDURE DISCOUNT/ PATIENT PP ADJST NET PRIMARY PRIMARY
DATE /DRG BILLED DISALLOWED CODE PORTION CODE ADJUSTMENT REASON WITHHOLD PAYMENT INSURANCE PAT PORT
========== ========= ========== ========== ========== ========== ==== ========== ====== ========== ========== ========== ==========
06/14/2017 S5102 76.27 0.00 288,289,C 0.00 4 0.00 76.27
06/15/2017 S5102 76.27 0.00 288,289,C 0.00 4 0.00 76.27
06/16/2017 S5102 76.27 0.00 288,289,C 0.00 4 0.00 76.27
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ---------- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Claim Totals: 228.81 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 228.81 0.00 0.00
CLAIM EOB SUMMARY
----------------------------------------
Claim Level Code: 
Claim Level Code: 
Interest Amount: 0.00
Penalty Amount: 0.00
PROCEDURE EOB/ADJUSTMENT SUMMARY
----------------------------------
Reason Code: 
Patient Portion Code:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will ask the User to select the `.txt` file and then it will read it out. It basically just goes trough each line and check if the beginning matches
`Claim #` and so on. It will output the Data on a new Sheet with the filename, if it already exists, it will do nothing.

```
Private Sub Read()
Dim fn As Variant, txt As String, x As Variant, Errors As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fname As String
Dim arr() As Variant, vTotal As Variant
Dim j As Long, k As Long: j = 2: k = 0

fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , _
       "Open File")
fname = Right(fn, Len(fn) - InStrRev(fn, "\"))
If fn = False Or sheetExists(fname) Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sht = Worksheets.Add
sht.Name = fname
sht.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Claim #"
sht.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Claim Total"
txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
x = Split(txt, vbNewLine)
For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    If Left(x(i), 8) = "Claim #:" Then
        If sht.Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" Then
            sht.Cells(j, 2).Value = "Not Found"
            j = j + 1
        End If
        sht.Cells(j, 1).Value = Right(x(i), Len(x(i)) - 9)
    ElseIf Left(x(i), 13) = "Claim Totals:" Then
        vTotal = Split(x(i), " ")
        sht.Cells(j, 2).Value = vTotal(2)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Function
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works Great! Thanks for the leg up. I'm not a programmer, I'm just a systems guys. I know enough to walk through code, figure out what it does, and make changes, I'm just not up to building out code from scratch. Thank you again!